# Apply multivariable linear regression to a dataset in pandas with sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, linear-regression

I'm trying to predict the population for states and the country in 2050. My current dataset has values for each state from 1951,1961...2011 in the same table. Here is a sample view:

```
Row States/Union Territories         1951   1961    1971    1981    1991    2001    2011
0   Andaman and Nicobar Islands   31    64       115     189     281     356    381
1   Andhra Pradesh               31115  35983   43503   53551   66508   76210   84581   
2   Arunachal Pradesh             307   337     468     632     865     1098    1384    
.
.
.
```

So i ran a simple regression for values in 2011 and the model works very well. My question here is, how do i run it for an entirely new column(2050), which has no data to compare with in order to test for accuracy or any other metrics? One thing i intuitively tried was to add a new column  as 2050 and put all the values as 0, but then even the predicted values were 0 so that's of no help. I'm new to this so thanks for any help!

Associated code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("final_doc.csv", encoding = "latin-1")
data.head()
data['2050'] = 0
X = data[['1951', '1961', '1971', '1981', '1991', '2001']].values
Y = data[['2011']].values
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2)
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
fin = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns = ['2011'])
fin
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/yratnadilla/ExamPractice_LinearRegression_PopulasiIndonesia/blob/master/04.py) is exactly what I was looking for. In short, the indices are set as the states and then transposed. After which linear regression can be simply applied eliminating the need for one-hot encoding. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The form of your model is incorrectly specified. You want to model your data so that your independent variables are year (a numeric variable) and state/union (a categorical variable). Your dependent variable will be the population size.

In order to develop such a model you will need to restructure your data so that it is in a [**long**](http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/reshape-wide-long-pandas-python-melt-function/) format (see below)

```
States/Union Territories      Year                Pop 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Andaman and Nicobar Islands   1951                 31
Andaman and Nicobar Islands   1961                 64
           ...                 ...                ...
Andhra Pradesh                1951              31115   
Andhra Pradesh                1961              35983
           ...                 ...                ...   
Arunachal Pradesh             1951                307
           ...                 ...                ...
```

Once the data is transformed into a proper format, you can then fit your model.
I should mention you will need to recode your categorical variable - you can use a method called [one hot-encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/) to achieve this.

Once your model has been fit, you will be able to predict the expected population size for a given year and Union/State.

The following post [Multiple Linear Regression Model in 7 Steps with Python](https://medium.com/pursuitnotes/multiple-linear-regression-model-in-7-steps-with-python-c6f40c0a527) provides a great guide to developing a model.

Hope this helps!

Comment: After restructuring the table in the way you specified, i will have 231 rows.. That means a 8 bit vector as my one hot encoding, am i right?

Comment: It would also be worth to look into one-hot encoding of the "year" variable, since treating year as numeric imposes a linear trend over time. One-hot encoding could lead to a better fit.

Comment: @Peter I can only use linear regression as specified by my professor, whether it's a good fit or not

Comment: You can use dummy/one hot encoding (for years) in linear regression. This is a common practice.

Comment: @Peter but nwaldo stated that i should use one hot encoding for the categorical data instead, i.e the states/UT's. This leaves me confused due to conflicting opinions. Could you care to explain?

Comment: I think you lack a basic understanding of regression. This cannot be cured here in the forum. I suggest you have a good read of ISL, Ch.3.2-3.4 http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf

Comment: @need_to_know_now As Peter had mention, I would recommend reading those chapters to clear up the gap in understanding.

Comment: @Peter Great suggestion. I have a question for you, wouldn't you have to code year as a numeric variable in order to forecast into the future? I don't see how it's possible to forecast year 2050 if the variable is coded as a dummy variable. [reference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425585/linear-regression-date-as-dummy-variable#comment794550_425585)

Comment: @nwaldo Good point, i read the reference answer. I'm going through the book Peter suggested, but i need an immediate implementation solution since I need to finish this model within the next few days. I'm more well versed with working with images and CNN's so numerical data and regression is very different for me.

Comment: Thinking about is: in your case, it would be in fact better to use years as numeric. See my answer...

Answer (score 1):

You essentially look at population growth and consequently you could model growth rates directly. Here is a example in `R`.

First, get some data ([China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_China) in this case):

```
# Pop China rounded (mio.)
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_China
df = data.frame(c(547,609,667,715,818,916,981,1045),c(1950,1955,1960,1965,1970,1975,1980,1985))
colnames(df)<-c("pop","year")
df
```

This looks like:

```
   pop year
1  547 1950
2  609 1955
3  667 1960
4  715 1965
5  818 1970
6  916 1975
7  981 1980
8 1045 1985
```

Next I run a "normal" linear regression (level-level):

```
# Normal linear regression "level-level"
reg1 = lm(pop~year,data=df)
summary(reg1)

# Predict / plot result
pred1 = predict(reg1, newdata=df)
plot(df$year, pred1, type="b")
lines(df$year, df$pop, type = "o", col = "blue")
```

Results are not bad: Adjusted R-squared:  0.9891. Also the plot (actual vs. predicted) looks really good.

[image]

However, we can model growth rates directly using a "log-level" specification. In this case, the dependent variable $y$ simply is "transformed" to $log(y)$, so that the regression model looks like:

$$ log(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + u .$$

Note that the interpretation of $\beta_1$ has changed now. If you increase $x$ (the year) by one unit, $y$ changes (c.p. on average) by $100(\exp^{\beta_1}-1)$ percent. This is the average population growth rate in the period 1950-1985. Here in this example, the average growth rate was about 1.9 percent per year.

```
# Linear regression log-level
reg2 = lm(log(pop)~year,data=df)
summary(reg2)
reg2$coefficients[2]

# The average growth rate
exp(reg2$coefficients[2])-1

# Predict / plot result
pred2 = exp(predict(reg2, newdata=df))
plot(df$year, pred2, type="b")
lines(df$year, df$pop, type = "o", col = "blue")
```

Note that we see a slightly better model fit here, since log-level transformations usually can smooth out a little bit of "wonkiness" in the data. We can also look at the plot.

[image]

Next we can move to "out of sample" prediction until 2015.

```
# "Out of sample" prediction
preddf = data.frame(c(1950,1955,1960,1965,1970,1975,1980,1985,1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2015))
colnames(preddf)<-c("year")
pred3 = exp(predict(reg2, newdata=preddf))

# Actual figures
actual = c(547,609,667,715,818,916,981,1045,1135,1204,1263,1304,1338,1375)
result = data.frame(cbind(preddf,round(pred3),actual))
colnames(result)<-c("year","pred","act")
result

# Plot results
plot(result$year, result$pred, type="b")
lines(result$year, result$act, type = "o", col = "blue")
```

The results look like:

```
   year pred  act
1  1950  551  547
2  1955  606  609
3  1960  666  667
4  1965  733  715
5  1970  806  818
6  1975  887  916
7  1980  976  981
8  1985 1073 1045
9  1990 1180 1135
10 1995 1298 1204
11 2000 1428 1263
12 2005 1571 1304
13 2010 1728 1338
14 2015 1900 1375
```

[image]

Wow... Bonkers! What happend? Well, aparently China's population growth did change. Growth decreased and we are not able to capture this trend in the data. What could be done? Maybe use (non-linear) generalised additive models, e.g. with regression splines. However, this will likely give poor results. Alternatively, I could estimate future growth only based on the last three or four observations, assuming that they are most representative for future growth. Note the differend trend in population growth between 1975 and 1985 (looks "flatter"). We could use this more recent patterns to get a better estimate.

Find an application of this technique (log-level linear regression) to Covid-19 on [this Github](https://github.com/Bixi81/COVID-19).

Splendid! Someone just did your homework ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort you have put into this answer, however im still at a loss on how to actually implement this in Pandas and sklearn, which was my original question. I understand that you've explained the logic behind approaching it which i really appreciate, but my question is still unanswered. I HAVE to implement is using linear regression since those are the course specifications, so changing the model is of no use. I was really looking for some exact implementation details for prediction of a future year . Thank you once again for a great answer,

Comment: The example above is linear regression

Comment: But it's in R. I said i needed implementation help using pandas and sklearn specifically, thanks!

Comment: I can‘t do all of your homework...

Comment: I'm not asking you to do any of it. I need explicit help with a particular issue which i have explained in my question very clearly.

Comment: ISL Python code may be helpful: https://github.com/JWarmenhoven/ISLR-python